# NPE при передаче интента провайдеру

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

Ломается приложение при попытке передать интент с текстом провайдеру.
Вывод отладки:

```
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.setIntent(MainActivity.java:33)
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:25)
```

Вот код с вызовом:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//загрузка меню
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);//получить ссылку на провайдер
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();//присвоить провайдер приватной переменной
    setIntent("This is example text");//25 строчка
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setIntent(String text){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);//33 строчка
}
```

Я подумал, что при передаче интента ещё просто не существует провайдера и переместил передачу интента в метод onOptionsItemSelected , но там происходит та же ошибка. В чём же проблема?

Comment: покажите импорт провайдера: суппорт или обычный?

Comment: import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

Comment: если меню суппорт, используйте `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem)`

Comment: Меню тоже всё обычное import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

Comment: все равно попробуйте ;)